# How to return variable from evaluate function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

How can I return something from `evaluate` in a variable?

```
async function myFunction(page, parentID, elementID)
{
  var childElement; 

  await page.evaluate((parentID, elementID) => {
    var parentElement = getParentElement(parentID);
    childElement = parentElement.getChildElement(parentElement, elementID); // SET THIS VALUE TO var childElement ??

  }, parentID, elementID);

  console.log(childElement.id);
}
```

Here I want to set something in `var childElement`. How can I do it?

This thing doesn't work. It says that there is no id of undefined.

Comment: For future reference: puppeteer has excellent documentation - https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
async function myFunction(page, parentID, elementID)
{
  var childElement = await page.evaluate((parentID, elementID) => {
    var parentElement = getParentElement(parentID);
    return parentElement.getChildElement(parentElement, elementID); 
  }, parentID, elementID);

  console.log(childElement.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are setting values in "childElement" which was empty at first but later you are extracting **childElement.id**, so thre are possibility that you arent getting id key in childElement. I suggest first use

```
 console.log(childElement)
```

so you will know better, which value you are getting.
And you are already setting value of childElement by doing this

```
childElement = parentElement.getChildElement(parentElement, elementID)
```

Better check this first, see what exactly you are getting by doing this. Since most of the values are undefined, I cant write a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Can you please try using promises ?
async function myFunction(page, parentID, elementID)
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      page.evaluate((parentID, elementID) => {
        var parentElement = getParentElement(parentID);
        var childElement = parentElement.getChildElement(parentElement, elementID);
    
        resolve(childElement)
      }, parentID, elementID);
      }).catch(function (err) {
        return util.returnExceptionAsPromise(err);
      });
}

// And then call this function like this
myFunction(page, parentID, elementID).then(childElement => {
    console.log('childElement', childElement)
})
```

Comment: This is literally just the same thing as to when using async/await, you just rewrote the answer in promise format which async/await does the same behind the scene.

Comment: @famoha I know but I prefer using promises,, that is why suggested this approach.

Comment: i mean it just over-complicates a simple matter for the person who asked the question. they used async/await so it would be better to probably also give them an answer in the format they probably understand better and easier.

Comment: Yup !  Got your point. Your solution looks more relatable to the question. But still I would go with promises in such situation. No offence :)